# Building InstallShield project with Multiple Product configuration using MSBuild command line

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, installshield, installshield-2012

I have created InstallShield Basic MSI project from Visual Studio (IS 2012 Spring, VS 2010). My InstallShield project having 2 product configurations and each configuration having one release. 
Product Configuration 1
    Release 1
Product Configuration 2
    Release 2

For building project in VS IDE, I need to set the corresponding product configuration as 'Default Product Configuration' and build. This is working fine. The Default configuration release is getting build.

But, how can we achieve this in MSBuild command line?

I need to build both configuration separately using MSBuild command line (without changing Default configuration through IDE).

Could anyone please share the proper way to build IS project in MSBuild command line?

Thanks,
Saravanan

Comment: Any update for this issue? Could you get useful information from answer? If not, you can add comment let us to know the latest status for this question, we will follow it up.

Answer (score 1):

> how can we achieve this in MSBuild command line?

You can use [Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171458.aspx) in the MSBuild command line:

```
msbuild test.sln /t:project /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x86" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

You can also build multiple projects at once:

```
msbuild test.sln /t:project;project2 /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="x86" /p:BuildProjectReferences=false
```

Note:

- what is assigned to /t is the project name in the solution, it can be different from the project file name.
- One important note: if your project has a '.' in the name, you'll need to replace it with a '_' when specifying it with /t

Comment: It is fine for VS project. But for InstallShield project with different "Product Configuration" bound with different arguments. I am not sure, but now trying the below link 
http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/MSBuild.htm